# Autowiring is not working in Apache Shiro custom Realm class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations, shiro

Currently I am using apache shiro authentication in my spring boot project. I wrote Custom Realm for Cassandra DB. While autowiring the class inside realm object returns null when submitting login details. My Application Config(@component annotation used):

```
@Bean(name = "realm")
@DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public ApplicationRealm realm() {
    ApplicationRealm realm = new ApplicationRealm();
    realm.init();
    return realm;
}

@Bean
public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

My Application Realm Class :

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.scm.auth")
public class ApplicationRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

@Autowired
IAuthRepository authRepo;

@Override
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
    try {
        roles.add("admin");
    } catch (Exception rEx) {
        throw new AuthorizationException(rEx);
    }
    SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(roles);
    info.setRoles(roles);

    return info;
}

@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = null;
    UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;

    User user = authRepo.findByUserName(upToken.getUsername(), true); // my model class

        try {
            if (user.getCurrentPwd().equals(upToken.getPassword())) {
                info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, user.getCurrentPwd(), getName());
            } else {
                throw new AuthenticationException("Login name [" + upToken.getUsername() + "] not found!");
            }
        } catch (Exception idEx) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(idEx);
        }
        return info;


}
```

Is any annotation missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the you have configured the mismatched annotation. Your ApplicationRealm.java should no have @Configuration annotation. @Component is enough for this Custome Realm.

```
 /*@Configuration*/
 @ComponentScan("com.scm.auth")
 public class ApplicationRealm extends AuthorizingRealm{
 /**/
 }
```